# Should Frames inherit from each other?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, oop

I am wondering if i should make a frame inherit from another. From the OOP view it would be good - one frame is an extension of another, would save the duplicated code in the extended one.

But what about Visual Studio Designer.cs file? What about the Design page, will it jump to the base frame, or disallow editing the derived one?

Comment: Why don't you just try out what will happen? It takes you no more than five minutes.

Comment: OK should have made a new test frame. Instead i was trying to convert an existing copy, got buried in errors and reverted back. I now see it works, of course ;)